# How to bind Dictionary with ComboBox and textbox?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a `Dictionary<String,Person>`, where Person is a class, defined below

```
String role;

public class Person
{ 
  public string firstname{ get; set; } 
  public string lastname{ get; set; } 

  public string city{ get; set; } 
}
```

My question is how to bind the Dictionary key: String  with a ComboBox, meanwhile. have the  Dictionary value: Person connected with three textboxes. That is, once a key is selected in the ComboBox, the corresponding value, firstname, lastname, city are shown in the three textboxes respectively?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Note: Not copy-pastable code... exists solely to get the point across.

### View

I see some controls with the databinding as shown below in the Window/View...

```
<Combobox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AlphabeticalIds}" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedId}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson.FirstName}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson.LastName}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson.City}"/>
```

### ViewModel

An instance of this class is set as the datacontext of the view. It has the following members. (They're exposed as .NET Properties ; NotifyPropertyChange calls identify the properties that require change notification)

```
_mapIdToPerson = Dict...

_alphabeticalIds = _map...Keys.Sort();

_selectedId;
set 
{
  _selectedId = value;
  _selectedPerson = _mapIdToPerson[_selectedId];
  NotifyPropertyChange("SelectedId");
  NotifyPropertyChange("SelectedPerson");
}

_selectedPerson;
```